# Capture Unity Audio Output Instead of "audiosource.clip"?

Tags: unity-game-engine, wwise

Have a Unity project using the Wwise audio input plugin. Plugin is sending audio out from Unity via a single Unity "audiosource.clip"

Is there a way we can change that so that the main unity audio output buss replaces the single Unity audio source slip? That way we can send all unity audio (main left and right stereo output) out to Wwise not just one audio clip inside Unity

Below is current example:

```
> using System.Collections;
> using UnityEngine;
> using UnityEngine.Events;
> [UnityEngine.RequireComponent(typeof(UnityEngine.AudioSource))]
> public class AkMicrophone : UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour
> {
> public AK.Wwise.Event MicrophoneEvent;
> public AK.Wwise.RTPC MicrophoneLevelRTPC;
> public int SampleRate = 48000;
> public int InitialReadDelayInSamples = 4096;
> [UnityEngine.Header("Invoked on exceeding -48dB")]
> public UnityEvent OnMicrophoneAction;
> 
> public static AkMicrophone Instance
>   {
> get;
> private set;
>   }
> 
>   public bool IsAboveThreshold
>   {
> get
>       {
> bool Above = currentMicLevel > ATTACK_LEVEL_THRESHOLD;
> currentMicLevel = -48;
> return Above;
>       }
>   }
> 
> Buffering consts
> private const int NUMBER_OF_CHANNELS = 1;
>   private const int BUFFER_SIZE_IN_SECONDS = 2;
>   private int BufferSizeInSamples { get { return BUFFER_SIZE_IN_SECONDS * NUMBER_OF_CHANNELS * SampleRate; } }
> 
> Level monitoring
>   private float ATTACK_LEVEL_THRESHOLD = -24.0f;
>   private float currentMicLevel = -48;
>   
> Unity Microphone input handling
> private UnityEngine.AudioSource MicrophoneSource;
> private int ReadPosition = 0;
>   public bool IsPlaying { get { return m_PlayingID != AkSoundEngine.AK_INVALID_PLAYING_ID; } }
>   private float[] SamplesBuffer = null;
>   private object BufferLock = new object();
> 
>   private uint m_PlayingID = AkSoundEngine.AK_INVALID_PLAYING_ID;
> 
> void AudioFormatDelegate(uint playingID, AkAudioFormat audioFormat)
>     {
> audioFormat.channelConfig.uNumChannels = NUMBER_OF_CHANNELS;
> audioFormat.uSampleRate = (uint)SampleRate;
>     }
> 
> public int samplePerFrame;
>   bool AudioSamplesDelegate(uint playingID, uint channelIndex, float[] samples)
>   {
> 
> if (IsPlaying)
>       {
> 
> samplePerFrame = samples.Length;
> Debug.Log("   delegate samples.Length " + samples.Length);
> 
> try
>           {
> lock (BufferLock)
>               {
> System.Array.Copy(SamplesBuffer, 0, samples, 0, samples.Length);
> ReadPosition = (ReadPosition + samples.Length) % BufferSizeInSamples;
>               }
>           }
> catch (System.Exception e)
>           {
> UnityEngine.Debug.LogError("Wwise Audio Input, exception occured: " + e.ToString());
> return false;
>           }
>       }
> 
> Return false to indicate that there is no more data to provide. This will also stop the associated event.
> return IsPlaying;
>     }
> 
> 
>   public bool checkBufferEnd;
> 
> 
>   public void playOneShot()
>   {
> 
> StopSound();
> 
> ReadPosition = 0;
> 
> m_PlayingID = AkAudioInputManager.PostAudioInputEvent(MicrophoneEvent.Id, gameObject, AudioSamplesDelegate, AudioFormatDelegate);
> 
> checkBufferEnd = true;
> 
> playedOnce = false;
>   }
> 
> 
>   public bool playedOnce = false;
>   bool checkOneShotEnded()
>   {
> 
> if (checkBufferEnd)
>       {
> if (ReadPosition >= SamplesBuffer.Length - samplePerFrame)
>           {
> 
> return true;
>           }
> 
> return false;
> return;
>       }
> 
> return false;
>   }
>   
>   void GetMicrophoneSamples()
>   {
> if (MicrophoneSource != null && MicrophoneSource.clip != null)
>       {
> 
> Debug.Log("  get mic sample ReadPosition : " + ReadPosition + "  length" + MicrophoneSource.clip.length +
> buffersize: " + SamplesBuffer.Length  + "   BufferSizeInSamples: " + BufferSizeInSamples);
> 
> 
> if (checkBufferEnd)
>           {
> if (ReadPosition >= SamplesBuffer.Length - samplePerFrame)
>               {
> 
> playedOnce = true;
> 
> StopSound();
> 
>               }
> 
> if(playedOnce)
> return;
> 
> return;
>           }
> 
> lock (BufferLock)
>           {
> 
> if(!checkOneShotEnded())
> MicrophoneSource.clip.GetData(SamplesBuffer, ReadPosition);
> 
>           }
>       }
>   }
> 
>   void Update()
>     {
> GetMicrophoneSamples();
> 
> if (IsPlaying)
>         {
> int RTPCValue = (int)AkQueryRTPCValue.RTPCValue_GameObject;
> AkSoundEngine.GetRTPCValue((uint)MicrophoneLevelRTPC.Id, gameObject, m_PlayingID, out currentMicLevel, ref RTPCValue);
> if (IsAboveThreshold)
> OnMicrophoneAction.Invoke();
>         }
>   }
> 
>   IEnumerator Start()
>   {
> if (Instance != null)
>       {
> UnityEngine.Debug.LogError("Wwise Microphone input: Attempted to add a second AkMicrophone component.");
> yield break;
>       }
> Instance = this;
> 
> yield return null;
> 
> SamplesBuffer = new float[BufferSizeInSamples];
> StartSound();
>   }
> 
>   public void StartSound()
>   {
> if (!IsPlaying)
>       {
> MicrophoneSource = GetComponent<UnityEngine.AudioSource>();
> MicrophoneSource.clip = UnityEngine.Microphone.Start(null, true, BUFFER_SIZE_IN_SECONDS, SampleRate);
> GetMicrophoneSamples();
> 
> Since GetData gives a LOT of data, move our ReadPosition closer to the current samples upon first read
> ReadPosition = UnityEngine.Microphone.GetPosition(null) - InitialReadDelayInSamples;
> ReadPosition = (ReadPosition + BufferSizeInSamples) % BufferSizeInSamples;
> 
> Debug.Log(" ReadPosition " + ReadPosition);
> 
> m_PlayingID = AkAudioInputManager.PostAudioInputEvent(MicrophoneEvent.Id, gameObject, AudioSamplesDelegate, AudioFormatDelegate);
>       }
>   }
>   public void StopSound()
>     {
> m_PlayingID = AkSoundEngine.AK_INVALID_PLAYING_ID;
> MicrophoneEvent.Stop(gameObject);
>   }
> 
> private void OnDestroy()
>     {
> StopSound();
>     }
> }
```

So far audio from the audioclip is getting sent to Wwise from Unity. Problem is want to use several clips and atm only allows for one at a time. Another possibkle spoultion is to be able to have multiple audioclips sent out to audio input plugin. Any thoughts are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution, but hopefully will steer you in the right direction.

Your clip is coming from an AudioSource component's clip.

```
MicrophoneSource = GetComponent<UnityEngine.AudioSource>();
MicrophoneSource.clip = UnityEngine.Microphone.Start(null, true, BUFFER_SIZE_IN_SECONDS, SampleRate);
```

I think you would need to either script this functionality yourself (`GetMicrophoneSamples()` might be a good place to start) or use different instances of the `AkMicrophone` MonoBehavior class.